# MediaDevice applyConstraints doesn't work

Tags: javascript, constraints, html5-video, mediastreamtrack

I am trying to apply new constraints to the video track, but it doesn't work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad();">
    <p id="res1"></p>
    <p id="res2"></p>
<script>
    async function onLoad() {
        var opts1 = {audio: true, video: {advanced: [{ width: 1280, height: 960 },]}};
        var stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(opts1);
        var cstr1 = stream.getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings();
        document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML = cstr1.width + ", " + cstr1.height;

        var opts2 = {audio: true, video: {advanced: [{ width: 640, height: 480 },]}};
        await stream.getVideoTracks()[0].applyConstraints(opts2);
        cstr2 = stream.getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings();
        document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML = cstr2.width + ", " + cstr2.height;
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the answer "1280, 960" before applying the constraints and "640, 480" after. But I see "1280, 960" instead.
Why? How can I apply it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to apply the `video` value of `opts2` as the `constraints` parameter of `applyConstraints(constraints)` for it to work.

```
var opts2 = { advanced: [{ width: 640, height: 480 }] }
await stream.getVideoTracks()[0].applyConstraints(opts2)
```

If you look at the `MediaTrackConstraints` properties on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints) you can see that there are no `audio` or `video` properties.

Comment: Did this fix the issue for you?